# Need for transit visa

Tags: visas, transit

Do I require a transit visa if I'm travelling to Ghana from China through Heath row Airport by British Airlines

Comment: What is your country of citizenship?

Comment: We cannot answer this question with the information given.

Comment: Assuming you're Ghanaian and live in Ghana, yes, you do need a UK airside transit visa. However, you have to tell us what passport you have and where you live for us to be able to give a definite answer

Answer (score 0):

The UK keeps a list of countries whose citizens will require a visa to transit or visit the UK. So it's all based on nationality.

You did not tell us your nationality so the answer to your question is *indeterminate*.

What can be done in situations like these is to point you to a web site sponsored by the UK government called [Check if you need a UK visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa).  This site uses the 'wizard pattern' to ask some questions and then make a determination.

Once you have learned if you need a visa or not, you can return here to ask specific questions about the form and evidence.